# When communicating via Bluetooth how can I select the bt module to be paired from the set of paired devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm struggling for a while with the aforementioned problem. I'd like to get a list of paired bluetooth devices (this seems to be fine by now) and being aware of what the required bluetooth module's MAC address is, simply selecting this MAC address and using it later as a parameter. I'm having troubles with trying to pick out the 30:14:10:17:06:93 address from the list.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    TextView devicesInPairWithPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.devicesInPairWithPhone);
    devicesInPairWithPhone.setText(pairedDevices.toString());

    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)  {
        if (device.toString().equals("30:14:10:17:06:93")) {
            mDevice = device;
            textView.setText(device.toString());
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("Selecting the correct bt module was unsuccessful.");
        }
    }
```

In this case on textView (I know, not an intuitive name, sorry for that) I get "Selecting the correct bt module was unsuccessful." all the time, i.e. the if(){} condition is never met. On devicesInPairWithPhone I get a fair set though: [30:14:10:17:06:93, 6C:0E:0D:E2:blablabla, ...]

Does someone have any idea what the problem might be? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my fault, I didn't pay attention to the fact that as the loop is iterating it will eventually print out "Selecting the correct bt module was unsuccessful." for the last element of the Set, thus this is what we will see on the screen.